# Showing only unique Values in the Selectbox/dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to get the data from the SQL server DB and place the respone in to the fields in the frontend. I am getting data but certain fields in the response is not unique and shows repeated values in the dropdown. My Component is like below

```
export class ReportingFilterComponent implements OnInit {
 ShipmentList: ShipmentByProject[];
 output= [];
 entityUrl = 'ShipmentDetail/GetByReportingProject?repPrj=000634';

 constructor(service: DataService) {
 this.ShipmentList = [];
 service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => {this.ShipmentList = x });
  }


 ngOnInit() {
  var flags= [];
  var l = Array.isArray(this.ShipmentList) ? this.ShipmentList.length : 0, i;
   for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name]) continue;
    flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name] = true;
    this.output.push(this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name);
  }}
```

To test I used the `output` array in the html

```
 Output data!
<li *ngFor="let out of output">
     {{ out.customer_shipto_name }}
</li>

<div class="dx-fieldset">
<div class="dx-field">
    <div class="dx-field-label">ShipTo Account</div>
    <div class="dx-field-value">
        <dx-select-box [dataSource]="ShipmentList" displayExpr="customer_shipto_name"></dx-select-box>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I dont get anything in the `output` even though `ShipmentList` has data on it. 
[image]

Comment: Assuming your `service.get<ShipmentByProject>[]>` call returns a promise, it would appear that `this.ShipmentList` will be undefined until the promise resolves. You could initialize the value as an empty array to get rid of the error, or check for presence of it before attempting to read the length.

Comment: @JoshRutherford how can I do that, sorry for being blunt first time programming in Angular

Comment: No problem, see posted answer

Comment: @JoshRutherford I have the ShipmentList intialized from the model class `ShipmentByProject`

Comment: What you have done here is specified the type of `ShipmentList` (using the colon syntax), but you haven't given it a value. That would look like `ShipmentList: ShipmentByProject[] = []`

Comment: @JoshRutherford Updated the question with what I tried on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want show data of ShipmentList when data that is returned from your service/api.

Also, you need instance variable for output. something like below. Try debugging your code.

```
export class ReportingFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  ShipmentList: ShipmentByProject[];
  entityUrl = 'ShipmentDetail/GetByReportingProject?repPrj=000634';
  output = [];

  constructor(private service: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const flags = [];
    this.service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => {
      if (x && x.length > 0) {

        this.ShipmentList = x;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.ShipmentList.length; i++) {
          if (flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name]) continue;
          flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name] = true;
          this.output.push(this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name);
        }
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `service.get<ShipmentByProject>[]>` call returns a promise, it would appear that `this.ShipmentList` will be undefined until the promise resolves. You could initialize the value as an empty array to get rid of the error, or check for presence of it before attempting to read the length.

You can initialize `ShipmentList` ahead of time:

```js
class YourClass {
    ShipmentList = [];

    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or initialize it in the constructor:

```js
constructor() {
    this.ShipmentList = [];
    service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => 
{this.ShipmentList = x });
  }
}
```

Or to check for it before reading the length:

```js
var l = Array.isArray(this.ShipmentList) ? this.ShipmentList.length : 0;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and updated the question with the code change. And screenshot of what I am seeing in the screen

Comment: `ngOnInit` will be called _before_ your subscription resolves.

You should move your code from `ngOnInit` to your `ShipmentList` subscription.. or better yet use an async pipe.

Answer (score 0):

So that error being thrown is in your `ngOnInit` block. Is `this.ShipmentList` undefined?

Also, to access `output` in your angular template, it needs to be a property *of* the component class. At the top of your class you should put `public output = []` and target that instead.

Comment: That output should be `public`, not `private` if you want it to be available in the template.

Comment: @JonKoops Oops yes, very true. It'll work but it won't pass AoT. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using data which are not loaded yet. What you have in the `ngOnInit` method should be in the subscribe above.

As @Ash mentioned the `output` property should be a class property and not defined in the `ngOnInit`.

Note 1: don't use `var`, use `const` or `let` instead. As those two exist in the block where they are.

Note 2: use camelCase in Typescript, so for example `ShipmentList` should be `shipmentList`